# HTML/CSS hover does not work as expected in column layout

Tags: html, css, web

I have a column layout design where I will have some fields on the left, and--when hovering one such field--info about them on the right. However, I can't seem to get it working. Please let me know what you think.

**EDIT** I am totally flexible to changing the HTML, CSS, or both. Also, I would prefer not to use javascript, if possible.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="content-left">
         <p class="one">This is page1 left content</p>

    </div>
    <div class="content-right">
         <p class="one_info">This is page1 right content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-left{
    background-color: #bcc5d8;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.content-right{
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:15px;
    //margin-bottom:16px;
}

.one_info{
    opacity:0;
}

.one:hover .one_info{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Code in motion:
https://jsfiddle.net/828qthhq/3/

Comment: Unfortunately it's not quite that easy. You'll need to restructure your HTML to get this to work. Currently as it stands your CSS `:hover` is changing the opacity of `.one_info` nested ***within*** `.one`. This doesn't fit your structure outlined above as `.one` does not contain any elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is written in a way such that .one_info will only get an opacity of 1 if it is a child of .one.

In other words, you would get the desired effect using the following HTML.

```
<div class="one">
    Always visible
    <div class="one_info">Show on hover</div>
</div>
```

In order to use your current HTML and still get the desired effect, you would need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the way you're doing it is a tad off! Here is a solution using javascript! I added onmouseover and onmouseout events to the first div which call a JS function to toggle the opacity.

```
<script>
    function toggleInfo(on){
        var styleToSet;    
        if(on){
            styleToSet = "opacity:1";
        } else{
            styleToSet = "opacity:0";
        }

        document.getElementById("test").style=styleToSet;   
    }
</script>

<div id="content">
    <div class="content-left" onmouseover="toggleInfo(1)" onmouseout="toggleInfo(0)">
         <p class="one">This is page1 left content</p>

    </div>
    <div class="content-right">
         <p id="test" class="one_info">This is page1 right content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```